# holomorphic function $f: B(0;1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{2+n}{3+n}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Does there exist a holomorphic function $f: B(0;1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{2+n}{3+n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}, n>1$?

Suppose f is holomorphic. Consider the function $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{2z+1}{3z+1}$.Then the zeros of the function $g(z)$ are $\{ \frac{1}{n} \}$ which has a limit point in $B(0;1)$. I want to use identity theorem but $g(z)$ is not holomorphic at $z=-\frac{1}{3}$... How to solve this problem?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: first restrict to $B(0, 1/4)$ say where $g$ is holomorphic, conclude it is zero there, hence $f=\frac{2z+1}{3z+1}$ there; but then by the identity theorem $f$ would need to be that everywhere and that is a contradiction as you noted

Comment: @Conrad Thank you!

Comment: happy to be of help